# Trying to write a SQL expression that drops a collection of rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've indexed my email inbox and have a table of `email_addresses`, `thread_id`, `subject`, `to`, `from`...etc

I would like to "group" (but `group by` doesn't work) the rows by email address, and then eliminate that collection of rows if any row inside that collection contains a certain email address inside the `to` field.

I've tried:

```
select *
from emails
where emails.[to] != "test@email_address.com"
```

But that just eliminates individual rows, and not the collection of rows that share an email address.

Unfortunately using `group by` loses all information beyond the top level row and the database no longer can check to see if there are other rows with that email address in the `to` field.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Your query is invalid (standard) SQL.

Comment: SQLLite, that was merely an example of what I was trying to do. The answer below works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `group by` on email_address and a conditional check for any of the to email specified.

```
select email_address
from emails
group by email_address
having count(case when emails.[to] = 'test@email_address.com' then 1 end) = 0
```

If you need the entire row information for such email_addresses use

```
select * from emails where email_address in (
select email_address
from emails
group by email_address
having count(case when emails.[to] = 'test@email_address.com' then 1 end) = 0)
```